# ng-table going to first page when data changes

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ngtable, angular-meteor

I'm working on a meteor app that uses angular-meteor and ng-table. The dataset of the ng-table is from a collection. You can add rows to the table dynamically via a modal form. The dataset is reactive and changes the view once there's a change in the collection. I'm watching for status changes of the item (`QUEUED`, `PROCESSING`, `CREATED`).

Thing is, if the table is on page 2 and the status changes (any change in the dataset), the table is redrawn and goes back to page 2. Is there a way to make it stay on the current page even with dataset changes?

Here's a sample of what I have so far:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function myController($scope, $reactive, ngTableParams, ngTableEventsChannel, myService) {
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);

        this.subscribe('myCollection');

        this.currentPage = 1;
        this.helpers({
            tableParams: () => {
                return new ngTableParams({
                    page: this.currentPage
                }, {
                    //this is just a simple collection call
                    dataset: myService.getItems().fetch()
                });
            }
        });

        $scope.$watch('vm.tableParams', (params) => {
            //not triggered :(
            ngTableEventsChannel.onDatasetChanged(() => {
                console.log('data changed');
                tableParams.page($scope.currentPage);
            }, $scope, tableParams);

            ngTableEventsChannel.onPagesChanged(() => {
                $scope.currentPage = tableParams.page();
            }, $scope, tableParams);
        });
    }

    angular.module('MyApp').controller('MyController', myController);
})();
```

The `onDatasetChanged` event isn't being triggered. I was going to change the page there but I'm not sure if that's a good idea anyway.

Comment: Please include any relevant HTML and packages in your question or provide a repository link so that we can reproduce your situation.

Comment: It should be this.$scope.$watch('vm.tableParams'